# iOS Instrument memory leak, 12.3.1 a lot, but 10.3.3 nothing

Tags: ios, objective-c, instruments

I used instrument to check for memory leaks.
There are three devices，the versions are 12.3.1、11.3.1、10.3.3，but only 12.3.1 has memory leaks

Has anyone else seen it?

---

#### Environment and settings

- Xcode version: `10.3`
- Xcode Build Configuration: `Debug`
- Xcode Build Settings : `Debug Information Format: DWARF with dSYM File`
- Devices model: `iPhone 6s`
- Devices version: `12.3.1`
- Tool name: `instrument`
- Tool version: `10.3`
- Instrument Standard: `Leaks`

#### Steps:

1. Select `Leak Checks`, focusing on red memory leaks
2. In the bottom panel, focus on `Cycles & Roots`
3. The result `Cycles(16)`, all like this `Malloc 64 Bytes - 7 nodes`
4. Results `Root Leaks (334)`, all like this `Malloc 16.00 KiB`
5. Check any check `Stack Trace`, some can track the library, most of them can't track

---

I don't expect any memory leaks in 12.3.1, but sometimes I can find thousands of `Root Leaks`. Could I provide more information？

Is it necessary to locate the code in the library? Too difficult for me

Thanks so much in advance for your help!

Comment: Yes, without any code investigation no one will be able to help you. The amount of memory leaking is irrelevant to the root cause.

Comment: @Kamil.S I don't know what code to provide because the memory leak does not point to my code.

Comment: try to isolate the problem. Maybe it appears only on particular screen of the app.

Comment: @Kamil.S I am very sorry, do you mean that this problem may not exist on other pages?

Comment: Correct, maybe the problem exists only upon reaching some particular area of the app.

Comment: @Kamil.S Maybe I didn't describe it clearly. Currently I have three models of devices 12.3.1, 11.3.1, 10.3.3, but only 12.3.1 has a memory leak.

Comment: @Kamil.S In order to maintain the same test environment for the three devices, I have kept all three devices on the App homepage.

Comment: Yes I understand, but do your best to pin down when exactly the leak happens on the affected 12.3.1. Right away from app launch?

Comment: @Kamil.S What do you mean by checking the timing of memory leaks, should you check for memory leaks after the boot should be properly completed, not when it is booting?

Comment: @Kamil.S Thank you very much, you are the best person.

Comment: @Nullable There are some issues on XCode 12.3* where false positive memory leaks are being reported and that has addressed on latest beta version, Please check the beta version Release notes.